# Jquery Loop through fields and drop menus and display entry values into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops, foreach

Im trying to work out how to take form field values and selected drop down menu options using a single loop and display them into individual divs on the same page.

At the moment ive managed to only achieve this using repetitive code rather than using a single loop. The form will eventually be very long with many fields and drop down menus (select options), therefore a loop would be a better option.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

My code

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){

    $("#name").keypress(event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#d_name").text(stt);
    });

    $("#email").keypress(event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#d_email").text(stt);
    });

        $("#telephone").keypress(event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#d_telephone").text(stt);
    });

    $("#car").change(function(event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#d_type").text(stt);
    });

  $("#type").change(function(event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $("#d_type").text(stt);
    });

    });//]]> 
    </script>  

        </head>
        <body>

    Name:      
    <input type="text" value="" id="name"/>
    Email:
    <input type="text" value="" id="email"/>
    Telephone:
    <input type="text" value="" id="telephone"/>
    Car:
    <select id="car" >
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
    Type:
    <select id="type">
      <option value="automatic">automatic</option>
      <option value="manual">manual</option>
    </select> 

    Your Data
    Name: <div id="d_name" ></div>
    Email: <div id="d_email" ></div>
    Telephone: <div id="d_telephone" ></div>
    Car: <div id="d_car" ></div>
    Type: <div id="d_type" ></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: There is a car object in your question. Below answers can help you but I am not sure about the CAR object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$('input, select').change(function() {
    $('#d_' + this.id).text($(this).val());
});
```

To your edit:

```
var updateText = function() {
    $('#d_' + this.id).text($(this).val());
}

$('input').keypress(updateText);
$('select').change(updateText);
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kBGZ6/

Comment: Thank you soo much. Does this also work with check boxes and radio buttons?

Comment: My example doesn't work with radio buttons or check boxes. It's a bit more complicated then.

Comment: Thats okay. However, my only issue is that ... if one copies text and pastes into a field ... it does not display it into the divs. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Add input to the change event `$('select, input').change...`

Comment: Forgot to ask ... it doesn't seem to work with textarea fields.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Thank you for your help. I have only one more issue ... is it possible to empty or reset all fields/textareas/select drop menus when the page first loads up?

Comment: Well they should be empty on the first page load. Otherwise something is wrong. But you could reset those fields with `$('input, select, textarea').val('');`

Comment: Problem im getting now is that I need it to keep a default value for some hidden input fields and a submit button value. Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question anymore. You should accept one of this answers to close this question.

Comment: Okay sorry. I will add another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$(":input,:select").change(function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val(); // get the val
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  // get the id
    $("#d_" + id).text(val);  // use #d_ plus id to set the test to val
});
```

First line selects all `input` and `select` elements and adds processes the following function on change. This only works when the `id` of the `div` is `d_` plus the `id` attribute from the `form` element.

And if you really wanted to, you could do it in a single line:

```
$(":input,:select").change(function(event) {
    $("#d_" + $(this).attr('id')).text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However 'binarious' method is shorter.

Comment: I need to make it work with a textarea field ... is that possible?

Comment: @designer101 look at [.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) or [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) .. example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/kBGZ6/2/

Comment: Hi ManseUK, my script is almost complete, now is it possible to empty or reset all fields/textareas/select drop menus when the page first loads up? Not sure something to do with '(document).ready(function ()' ?